# Promise-based node http framework?

Tags: node.js, http, promise

Node frameworks usually work via `(err, result)` callbacks.

Is there a promise-based http framework for Node, with a healthy community and in active development (such as express)?

Comment: I use Q's `denodeify` wherever I have async workflows with nodejs functions. I've tried it on some external library functions as well, and it has worked fine for me. Do try out `Q.denodeify <express function>`.

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify.  I believe this question is asking for a node.js framework for an http server using promises, not a library for making promise based http requests, which some of the answers seem to be addressing.

Answer (score 12):

On the HTTP client side, there is the new `fetch API` https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/

> `fetch()` allows you to make network requests similar to XMLHttpRequest (XHR), The main difference is [it] uses Promises, which enables a simpler and cleaner API, avoiding callback hell and having to remember the complex API of XMLHttpRequest

(https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch)

Some implementations:

- Browser "poly-fill" (older browsers) https://github.com/github/fetch
- Node version https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch
- Cross platform version https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch (I don't like the word "isomorphic" used in this situation... anyway)

Here some example code:

```
fetch('/some/url', {method: 'get'})
  .then(function(response) {
    // rejoice \o/
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    // error :-(
  });
```

Comment: Why is this down voted? How does this not answer the question? This is a Node and promised based HTTP client, but maybe I am missing something...

Comment: The question is about server side

Comment: Well, the question by OP is somewhat ambiguous. If you look at my answer you see that there is both server and browser implementations of the fetch API.

Answer (score 7):

There is https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

> Promise based HTTP client for the browser and node.js

Example code:

```
// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question you had today, and I found [q-io](https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io), also by kriskowal. It uses Q.js to promise-wrap filesystem io as well as server and http client.

I have not tried it out yet, but it definitely does not seem to have an active community built around it at this point. Sad thing to see, in a world filled with callback pyramids of doom.

Comment: Haha "Callback pyramids of doom"

Answer (score 3):

You might be interested in [Joey](https://github.com/montagejs/joey) written by Kris Kowal, the author of the Q promise library. There's not a large community, but Kris is often on the #montage irc channel on freenode to offer help.

Answer (score 2):

Still not quite even in late 2016.

Others have skipped Koa.js which does support promises for its generator based 'async/await'.

Yet I think your question targets a much deeper integration, which might be what I've made: A http server that returns requests as promises that can then be chained together.

It's based on the idea that promises represent asynchronous tasks that can once be fulfilled, hence a server is like a stream of promises which I encapsulated in a callback evoked with a promise.

It's still more of a cool potential (i.e. for smaller, specialized projects) as there's very little code to it (and current concept sits at 0 dependencies)

There's more detail on this in the repository: https://github.com/rsxdalv/unframed
which includes a walk-through of the building process. With code that can actually be run Node.js v6.6

Answer (score 1):

For HTTP clients, I like http://www.npmjs.org/package/httpinvoke.

For HTTP servers, I like https://github.com/mjackson/mach ; it's great!

Then again, I'm not such a huge fan httpinvoke either, I works and it's okay. But I think the API is more complicated than it needs to be and I find it hard to debug. I might be missing something.

Alternatively, I use recommend [kew](https://github.com/Medium/kew) (fast promise implementation) to wrap callback style methods.

Answer (score 0):

You may try aex.

https://github.com/calidion/aex/

Aex is promise based, async / await only, no more callbacks framework written in typescript.

Aex is compatible with express middlewares with a simple function call.